# How can I compare CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: core-location, cllocation, equatable

I need a way of comparing two `CLLocationCoordinate2D`'s however when I tried using `==` it wouldn't work. Please can someone help me out with the best way of comparing them?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Either the generic approach for comparing two instances of any given struct type:

```
memcmp(&cllc2d1, &second_cllc2d, sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D))
```

or

```
cllc2d1.latitude == cllc2d2.latitude && cllc2d1.longitude == cllc2d2.longitude
```

should work, if you really want to be sure they're *exactly* equal. However, given that latitude and longitude are defined as doubles, you might really want to do a "close enough" comparison:

```
fabs(cllc2d1.latitude - cllc2d2.latitude) <= epsilon && fabs(cllc2d1.longitude - cllc2d2.longitude) <= epsilon
```

where `epsilon` is whatever level of error you want to accept.

Comment: The first might be considered sketchy, since you're making the assumption that the struct is packed without any bytes between the members.

Comment: Good point. If you zero the entire struct when it's created/allocated then the memcmp approach is safe even for non-packed structs, but otherwise, use with caution.

Comment: @Glenn can you please fix abs to fabs and < to <=.

Comment: what do you mean by zero the entire struct? And what do you mean that struct is packed without any bytes between the members? you mean it may not even be the case>?

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work for exactly equal locations and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. See my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200609/cant-compare-two-cllocationcoordinate2ds-negative-zero

Comment: The first approach is a completely unreliable approach. The second is difficult to use correctly. Why not just calculate the distance and compare the result with a minimum value where two locations are considered "equal"?

Comment: fyi, sizeof is now undefined

Answer (score 35):

As a small addition to all these answers, it's quite handy to have the comparison defined as a preprocessor define:

```
#define CLCOORDINATES_EQUAL( coord1, coord2 ) (coord1.latitude == coord2.latitude && coord1.longitude == coord2.longitude)
```

or with epsilon:

```
#define CLCOORDINATE_EPSILON 0.005f
#define CLCOORDINATES_EQUAL2( coord1, coord2 ) (fabs(coord1.latitude - coord2.latitude) < CLCOORDINATE_EPSILON && fabs(coord1.longitude - coord2.longitude) < CLCOORDINATE_EPSILON)
```

This allows you to do a comparison as follows:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D resultingCoordinate = ... a method call ...;
CLLocationCoordinate2D expectedCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(48.11, 11.12);

if(CLCOORDINATES_EQUAL( resultingCoordinate, expectedCoordinate)) {
    NSLog(@"equal");
} else {
    NSLog(@"not equal");
}
```

Another alternative is to use an inline method, if you don't like the preprocessor.

Comment: Never compare floating point numbers with `==`. See answers where people use `epsilon`.

Comment: @DanSkeel See my edited answer. Sometimes you have a use case where you want to compare exact coordinates. E.g. if the source for the coordinates is a place database and you only want to compare those. Then there is no need for a range for the equal comparison. So you might think about your down vote again.

Comment: You didn't get my point. Imagine the case when `1 != 0.99999999999` ... It's general rule for any floating point comparison. [Read about](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/) it. This rule is old as a computer.

Comment: I still don't get your point. If the source of your coordinates is e.g. a database and you don't do any computations with the coordinates it is just fine to use a regular == comparison.

Comment: But some one computed that coordinates. You mean that all that float coordinates were set manually by some person? Not a computer?

Comment: Im my case I let the user choose a location and save the coordinates into my database. From that point on the coordinates are fixed and will never change. To to syncing between multiple devices I need the exact coordinates, because the user could create two locations that are very close to each other.

Comment: Just a late clarification on the earlier comments here: the issue is *how* the coordinates are stored. Latitude and longitude are `Double` values by default. `Double` values are *rarely exact* in a computer. If the user enters a latitude, say, of `38.627003`, there's no guarantee that the computer will store exactly `38.627003`. A recent test printing a computer's interpretation to 15 decimal places returned a value of `38.627002716064453`! Now, if you retrieve and store the user's response as a `String`, *then* the result would be exact - but remember the *default* is `Double`.

Answer (score 25):

A Swift extension:

```
import MapKit

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D: Equatable {}

public func ==(lhs: CLLocationCoordinate2D, rhs: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {
    return (lhs.latitude == rhs.latitude && lhs.longitude == rhs.longitude)
}
```

[tested as of Xcode 7.3.1, Swift 2.2]
[and, of course, still has the intrinsic danger of comparing floating point values, so you might want to consider using `epsilon` as mentioned in earlier answers]

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [CLLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html) class' distanceFromLocation: method. The return value is a [CLLocationDistance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationdistance?language=objc), which is really just a double.

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

Answer (score 12):

In Swift 3, `DBL_EPSILON` is deprecated. Use `Double.ulpOfOne`.

```
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    func isEqual(_ coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {
        return (fabs(self.latitude - coord.latitude) < .ulpOfOne) && (fabs(self.longitude - coord.longitude) < .ulpOfOne)
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be `<= .ulpOfOne` instead of `< .ulpOfOne` because anything less than ulpOfOne is in effect zero by definition.

Answer (score 9):

You could define a function which feels pretty like coming from CoreLocation:

`BOOL CLLocationCoordinateEqual(CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate1, CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate2)
{
    return (fabs(coordinate1.latitude - coordinate2.latitude) <= DBL_EPSILON &&
            fabs(coordinate1.longitude - coordinate2.longitude) <= DBL_EPSILON);
}`

Comment: upvoted as this is the most maintainable solution IMO

Comment: Good solution. Here is the complete method just for new bee. -(BOOL)compairLastSavedCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D )coordinate1 withNewCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate2
{
    return (coordinate1.latitude == coordinate2.latitude) && (coordinate1.longitude == coordinate2.longitude);
}

Comment: Never compare floating point numbers! If you do, it's unreliable. In practice, most comparisons from real locations generated by different sources will return `false` - even if they are pretty close to each other and can be considered "equal".

Answer (score 6):

Updated for Swift 5 based on [leann's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1107226/leanne) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38578133/4475605).

```
import CoreLocation

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D: Equatable {
    static public func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        lhs.latitude == rhs.latitude && lhs.longitude == rhs.longitude
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D c1, c2;
if (c1.latitude == c2.latitude && c1.longitude == c2.longitude)
{
    // ...
}
```

I'm not kidding. CLLocationCoordinate2D is a C struct, and there's no easy way to compare C structs, apart from comparing the individual members.

Answer (score 1):

`CLLocationCoordinate2D` is a C struct, thus, you need to compare its fields:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord1, coord2;
if (coord1.latitude == coord2.latitude && coord1.longitude == coord2.longitude) {
    // coordinates are equal
}
```

Note, `CLLocationCoordinate2D` fields are `double`, thus, you may get the same issues like with any other floating point comparison. Thus, I suggest to round a little bit values, e.g.:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord1, coord2;
if (round(coord1.latitude * 1000.0) == round(coord2.latitude * 1000.0)
    && round(coord1.longitude * 1000.0) == round(coord2.longitude * 1000.0)) {
    // coordinates are equal
}
```

Yes, this, code is slower, but this may help you to avoid problems caused by not so perfect precision of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap `CLLocationCoordinate` into an `NSValue` using this function `+ (NSValue *)valueWithMKCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate`

And then use `isEqualToValue` to compare.

Quote from Apple doc of `isEqualToValue` function:

> The NSValue class compares the type and contents of each value object to determine equality.

Ref: Apple doc of [`NSValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/)

Answer (score 0):

We can convert latitude and longitude to NSString and do a string compare.

```
+ (BOOL)isEqualWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location1 withAnotherCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location2{
NSString *locationString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g, %g", location1.latitude, location1.longitude];
NSString *locationString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g, %g", location2.latitude, location2.longitude];

if ([locationString1 isEqualToString:locationString2]) {
    return YES;
}else{
    return NO;
}
```

}

Since %g will convert truncate decimal number to 4 digit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some tolerance value to handle Double comparison, with trial and error I found that 0.01 is an acceptable value.

```swift
import MapKit

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D: Equatable {
  public static func == (lhs: CLLocationCoordinate2D, rhs: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {
    let tolerance = 0.01
    return abs(lhs.latitude - rhs.latitude) < tolerance &&
    abs(lhs.longitude - rhs.longitude) < tolerance
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 5.3 way**

I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/NikKovIos/42808d2ef3831bd3d18171b4a144412e)

```swift
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D: Equatable {
    public static func == (lhs: CLLocationCoordinate2D, rhs: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {
        let numbersAfterCommaAccuracy: Double = 4
        let ratio = numbersAfterCommaAccuracy * 10
        let isLatitudeEqual = ((lhs.latitude - rhs.latitude) * ratio).rounded(.down) == 0
        let isLongitudeEqual = ((lhs.latitude - rhs.latitude) * ratio).rounded(.down) == 0
        return isLatitudeEqual && isLongitudeEqual
    }
}
```