# Can't compare two CLLocationCoordinate2Ds (negative zero??)

Tags: c, floating-point, core-location, cllocationcoordinate2d

I'm having the hardest time comparing two (what should be identical) `CLLocationCoordinate2D` structs in my iOS app. For some reason no matter how I compare them, the latitude just won't say it's equal.

The code:

```
double dlat = self.mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude - self.centerOnNextView.coordinate.latitude;
double dlong = self.mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude - self.centerOnNextView.coordinate.longitude;
NSLog(@"dlat: %f dlong: %f, dlat == 0.0: %d, dlat == -0.0: %d, dlong == 0.0: %d, dlong == -0.0: %d",
    dlat, dlong, dlat == 0.0, dlat == -0.0, dlong == 0.0, dlong == -0.0);
if ( ( dlat == 0.0 || dlat == -0.0 ) && ( dlong == 0.0 || dlong == -0.0 ) ) {
    NSLog(@"WE ARE EQUAL!");
}
```

I even tried `if ( [@(dlat) isEqualToNumber:@(0)] && [@(dlong) isEqualToNumber:@(0)] )` as the comparison check, but it failed too.

Here's the output:

```
dlat: -0.000000
dlong: 0.000000
dlat == 0.0: 0 (false)
dlat == -0.0: 0 (false)
dlong == 0.0: 1 (true)
dlong == -0.0: 1 (true)
```

For some reason I just keep getting that negative zero in there and nothing will compare against it. What the heck can I do to get these things to compare?!

Comment: What, nobody's on at 9:30 on a monday night? XD

Comment: It is likely that `dlat` is not 0. It might be that the precision of your printf is rounding it down for display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dlat` does not have the value of 0.0.  **Use `%e`** when printing instead of `%f` to see the difference.

Comparing a number to 0.0 as in `dlat == 0.0`  gets the same result as `dlat == -0.0`.  No need to do both compares.

---

More on -0
0.0 and -0.0 have the same *numeric* value and compare just like each other in the six compare operators >=, >, ==, !=, <, <=.

If one *must* distinguish between the zeros, one could use `int signbit()` or `memcmp()`.  Many methods exist.

Comment: You're right, it's actually -7.105427e-15 for some reason, even though I actually set the center coordinate to the same value previously. Strange indeed. I guess the only way is to do a < comparison.

Comment: 1. Either `self.mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude` or `self.centerOnNextView.coordinate.latitude` of type `float`?  2. Try `%a` for precise hexadecimal notation.  Likely your values differ by 1 bit.